# Convert 1d numpy array to 2d

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array A of shape (30,) where each row has a list with 2000 elements. I want to convert this into a 2d array of shape (30, 2000). This is what I tried

```
A = np.reshape(A, (30, -1))
```

But, running this gives me an array of shape (30, 1) rather than (30, 2000). What should I do to get the correct shape?

Comment: what is the datatype that you are aiming for ? , you currently have an array of objects, so it has 30 objects only, numpy has no idea what's inside these objects, you need to explicitly cast the array into your intended datatype (.astype()) instead of basic object so numpy will know how to reshape it (which won't be necessary)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where each row has a list with 2000 elements

As Ahmed Mohamed AEK points out in the comments this won't work as the numpy object is of shape `(30,)`. One easy fix is to stack them into a 30 by 2000 np.array.
For example:

```
A = np.vstack(A)
```

or equvalently:

```
A = np.stack(A, axis=0)
```